# How to connect SignalR clinet from Public IP?

Tags: c#, signalr, owin, signalr-hub, signalr.client

I have SignalR hub service and SignalR client. Lets say,

Scenario 1: 
I run my SignalR server in 172.100.20.55 and clinet in 172.100.20.80 or any other IP in the same domain.
For HubConnection, I use http://172.100.20.55:100 in server and client side. 
In this case, I will be able to communicate with server and client.

Scenario 2:
I run SignalR server in 172.100.20.55 and client in 172.100.20.80. 
For HubConnection I use, http://172.100.20.55:100 in server side and 
http://115.240.70.250:100 (115.240.70.250 is the public IP of 172.100.20.55). 
In this case, the server is started and client is not able to connect with the server since it is in the out of domain.

Here is my code:

Server side:

```
 private void StartServer()
    {
        try
        {
           IDisposable SignalR = WebApp.Start(http://172.100.20.55:100);
        }
        catch (TargetInvocationException exc)
        {
            throw;
        }           
    }
```

Client side:

```
    private async void ConnectAsync()
    {
        HubConnection Connection = new HubConnection(http://115.240.70.250:100);           
        HubProxy = Connection.CreateHubProxy("MyHub");           
        HubProxy.On<string, string>("AddMessage", (name, message) => //do something)
        );
        try
        {
            await Connection.Start();
        }
        catch (HttpRequestException exc)
        {
            throw;
        }

    }
```

When I try to connect client, it throws "**A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 115.240.70.250:100**"

Since I have connected my clinet in different network(in this case, I used my dongle network).

I want to connect the Public IP with the server. How am I suppose to achieve this? Any help would be really appriciated.

Comment: Start server on public and not internal ip? Or bind to all interfaces via `http://*:100`.

Comment: that also tried. In that case, Im not able to start the server. Also, my public IP will change. So I don't want that.

Comment: Not able how? Which exception is thrown?

Comment: "The format of the specified network name is invalid" Im getting this error when I try my public IP in server.

Comment: I have created Inbound rule in Firewall with some ports open (100,7222)as well. But it doesn't work.

Comment: That means this ip (115.240.70.250) does not belong to any network interfaces on your server. If you are behind some router - you need to configure port forwarding on that router, so that requests going to public ip of router (115.240.70.250) on port 100 are redirected to your machine.

Comment: @Evk, exactly you got the point. It doesn't belong to any network interface. I need to configure that. How can I do?

Comment: Your router manages your WAN IP. For public IP's to connect to internal services on your LAN, you would need to delegate all WAN traffic from TCP 100 to a specified IP on your LAN. This can be done using NAT (Network Address Translation).

Comment: Well that's different per router. Just look for how to configure port forwarding on your specific router. You need to forward port 100 from 115.240.70.250 (your router public ip) to 172.100.20.55 (your machine internal ip).